# Calculating correct dpi for my larger drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am creating a drawable for a button background resource. The button will be larger than the normal 48x48 for mdpi ( I would like to double it to 96x96). On the Iconography Google Dev page it says to use ~160dpi for the 48x48. So do I also double the dpi if my size is double the recommended size? Or is there a better way to calculate what the dpi should be for my drawable? This is a very important asset to me and I want to get it spot on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html
```

If you look at google dev, they advice to use :

48*48px
72*72px
96*96px
144*144px
.. etc

So it is more like  2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio (with a mdpi baseline at 48px and 160dpi)

YES if you double the size of the icons the DPI should also be doubled so for 96px it should be 320dpi

Comment: right, that's what I thought. Thanks for being my double check. I hate creating a bunch of drawables and then finding out that the size is off. Thanks!